# Always get -1 connection refused response from server

Tags: iot, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I am making a alert device on my node mcu board to report any orders made by customers on my application. The nodemcu should access the network using wifi and call the rest api. I tried researching many sites and modified the code several times, but the response is always -1, connection refused.

tried doing

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>   
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();

  for (uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
    Serial.printf("[SETUP] WAIT %d...\n", t);
    Serial.flush();
    delay(1000);
  }

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFiMulti.addAP("----", "----");
}

void loop() {
  // wait for WiFi connection
  if ((WiFiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) {

    WiFiClient client;
    HTTPClient http;

    Serial.print("[HTTP] begin...\n");
    if (http.begin(client, "http://34.87.116.113:80/api/v1/iot/Notify/poll")) {  // HTTP
     http.setAuthorization("admin", "admin123!");

      Serial.print("[HTTP] GET...\n");
      // start connection and send HTTP header
      int httpCode = http.GET();

      // httpCode will be negative on error
      if (httpCode > 0) {
        // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);

        // file found at server
        if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK || httpCode == HTTP_CODE_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) {
          String payload = http.getString();
          Serial.println(payload);
        }
      } else {
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
      }

      http.end();
    } else {
      Serial.printf("[HTTP} Unable to connect\n");
    }
  }

  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: is only on web server on that IP address?

Comment: On any ip address or rest api examples also . . Always -1. ..  only once during the first run it showed results then after even the same program returns -1

Comment: sorry a typo. is only one web server on that IP address?

Comment: Yes only one server

Comment: What happens if you hit this same endpoint with curl on a PC connected to the same wifi network?  What do the server's logs say?   Given that you've posted the account details to the world, that had better be a temporary test server!

Comment: I am able to view the page on desktop same wifi

Comment: Yes it is temporary test server

Comment: Examine the server logs.  Or run tcpdump or tshark on the wireless access point and examine the traffic.  You are looking for what is different between what the PC does and what the ESP does.

Comment: Where should i run tcpdump ? Sorry i am new to this